# Picturebox e datagridview

Tags: c#

Galera estou precisando de ajuda, já consegui fazer o upload de imagens para bd, agora estou com o seguinte problema:
Coloquei este código para selecionar uma linha da datagridview e preencher os respetivos campos.

```
txtIDMovie.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtNameMovie.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtRealizador.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtCatMovies.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        txtAnoMovie.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtClassIdade.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        txtClassIMDB.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        cbFormato.Text = dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
```

Para a imagem usei:

```
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        pbCapa.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Só que se quiser editar um campo que ainda não tenha imagem ao selecionar a linha dá erro.
Existe alguma forma de resolver?

Comment: só testar se dgvMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value é igual a null

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei e funcionou, o problema é que a base de dados fica muito lenta.
Existe outra forma de gravar sem ser imagem?

Comment: você pode gravar a imagem em disco e no banco de dados gravar só o caminho dela, não sei se é a melhor opção, mas é uma opção.

Comment: Como faço para gravar em disco?